# HTTP Status 505 Error while using REST API

Tags: rest, jersey-2.0

I just started learning REST API and jersey. When I run the application. I am getting this error and have no idea how to fix it.

[image: Error]

Can someone help in this? I want to know why I am getting this error even though I configured all the required jars and also I want to know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Seems like it unable to find needed class. Have you installed all requirements?

Comment: @MaximMazurok  I downloaded the zip file from jersey official site and then extended the below jars in WEB-INF/Lib folder  \jaxrs-ri-2.17\jaxrs-ri\api
\jaxrs-ri-2.17\jaxrs-ri\ext
\jaxrs-ri-2.17\jaxrs-ri\lib     I really have no clue where I am missing

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you haven't added the lib folder to build path . add lib folder to build path will resolve your problem.